# Check if user is logged in with Token Based Authentication in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, access-token

I managed to implement this token based authentication system in my application, but I have a little question. How can I check if a user is signed it (eg if the there is a valid token in the request) within the method? So with the [Authorize] ?

So I have controller, and in that controller I want to check if the user is signed in. I thought of using this:

```
if (_signInManager.IsSignedIn(ClaimsPrincipal.Current))
{
    ...
}
```

but it does not work since ClaimsPrincipal.Current is always null

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You don't need to use the SigninManager or something similar. The user is injected on the pipeline (on the User property of the base controller) and it's info is filled automatically by the authentication middleware (cookie or token). So, on your controller:

```
bool isAuthenticated = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
```

Comment: I tried your code but it says `The name 'User' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: Does your controller class inherit from "Controller" or is it a POCO?

Comment: Inheriting from Controller fixed that! I can't believe I forgot that!

Comment: This wont work if site is running as anonymous

Answer (score 4):

yes . put `[Authorize]` attribute above your class or methods to check if user is authenticate or not. You can get user by this code:

```
var principal = User as ClaimsPrincipal;
var check = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
```

Comment: I'd like to try it without [Authorize] first, but it says `The name 'User' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: You need the following namespace:

using System.Security.Principal;

Comment: I referenced that now but it makes no difference

Comment: or use HttpContext.Current.User

Comment: HttpContext.Current.User