# How to check if user is authenticated in Razor pages of .Net Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, razor, asp.net-core

I would like to check if a user is logged in in an ASP.NET Core 2.0 application in a Razor page. The following code worked in .NET 4.6.1:

```
@if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <p><a href="@Url.Action("Login", "Account")" class="btn btn1-success btn-lg" role="button" area="">Sign In &raquo;</a></p>
}
```

How can I do this in Core 2.0?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if user is logged in with Token Based Authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41315903/check-if-user-is-logged-in-with-token-based-authentication-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 132, accepted):

**Edit**: David is right of course.

Just check if `User` or `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is `true` or not.

```
@if(!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) 
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: This isn't correct. The user isn't null even when you're not authenticated.

Comment: I just change mine to `@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) { ... }` and it works as expected

Comment: It's works for on asp.Net Core 2.0 ~ @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {} ~

Comment: Works on .NET core 3.1 too

Answer (score 1):

I've always used this option.

```
 private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;

        public HomeController(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager)
        {
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            if (_signInManager.IsSignedIn(User)) //verify if it's logged
            {
                return LocalRedirect("~/Page");
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Hope it helps someone!