# asp.net - allow user to view page, but require password to make a post

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Can someone suggest a way to allow users to view pages anonymously, but require a login before the viewer can make a post on the pages? Kind of like message boards allow people to view them, but in order to make a post the viewer has to create an account and then login.

I use asp.net with vb.net.

Comment: Hello, @Hippo, and welcome to Stack Overflow. This may be too broad of a question to yield useful answers here, and especially without more detail to provide concrete suggestions. Generally, though, the answer is that you look at whether the user is authenticated via `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` and, if they are, provide the comment form and, if they aren't, include a prompt to login. How you log them in is obviously a much more involved topic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if user is authenticated in Razor pages of .Net Core 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45888275/how-to-check-if-user-is-authenticated-in-razor-pages-of-net-core-2-0)

Comment: Thank you, Jeremy.  That link was helpful.  I think that provides the information needed to do what I need to do.