# How to check if the user is signed in?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

```
try
{
    string signedInUserID = HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
    //do some stuff if the user is singed in
}
Catch
{
    //do some stuff if the user is singed in
}
```

Is there a better way to check if the user is signed in?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41315981

Answer (score 1):

You can always check using `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` like following.

```
    if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        //Authenticated 
    }
    else
    {
        //Not Authenticated
    }
```

**Note**: `Claims` are mainly used to store additional data and more for `Authorization` purpose.